# Laravel - Import File Using Octet-Stream

Tags: php, post, laravel-5, file-upload, parameters

I was curious if anyone has ever imported a file where the post parameters in the developer bar is formatted like below with the content-type being application/octet-stream?

Below is just the first couple of lines of the parameters sent in the post data:

```
-----------------------------24464570528145
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="RemoteFile"; filename="594.pdf"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

%PDF-1.5
1 0 obj
<<
/Creator ()
/CreationDate (2
```

I'm curious how I would upload the file through the model controller and I'm hoping someone else here might have run across this sort of issue.

Comment: shouldn't you get the file simply `$request->file('RemoteFile')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this one line of code

```
(new FileSystem)->put('/path/to/file.txt', $request->getContent());
```